Why is a symplectomorphism always required to be a diffeomorphism?
The usual definition on a symplectomorphism is a diffeomorphism $f : M \to N$ such that the symplectic form of N gets pulled back to the symplectic form of M.
However open immersions also pull back symplectic forms to symplectic forms, so why do we not define the morphisms of symplectic manifolds as smooth maps $f : M \to N$ pulling back the symplectic form of M to the symplectic form of N?

It sounds to me that you're asking a cultural question, not a mathematical one. In the hope of clarifying intent: (i) We can distinguish maps $f:(M_1,\omega_1) \to (M_2,\omega_2)$ between symplectic manifolds satisfying $f^*\omega_2=\omega_1$, and diffeomorphisms with the same property. Both concepts are presumably interesting. (ii) We can conventionally attach the term symplectomorphism to anything we like, including either class of mapping under item (i). The question of utility is, "What does the term suggest?" <> If you ask me, morphism suggests reversibility. Is that the question?

Well, no, morphism doesn't suggest reversibility; a morphism is just a map. But this fits in the hierarchy of homeomorphism, diffeomorphism, biholomorphism ... in the category of symplectic geometry.

@TedShifrin That's precisely the sense (those three examples in that order) in which to me morphism suggests reversibility, but my comment ran over the length limit and in paring down the nuance was omitted. :)

@AndrewD.Hwang I think it’s the three prefixes that give the “sameness,” rather than the “morphism.” Not sure about “symplecto,” but at that point mathematics proceeds by induction.

@TedShifrin That's fair, though if memory serves the term homeomorphism predates category theory by ... 30-50 years? <> On the other hand, given current trends mathematicians may some day speak of holomorphic maps as holomorphisms (or already do and I missed the memo), upon which a case could be made for ... dare one even suggest the Newspeak-y prospect ... symplectomorphism and bisymplectomorphism. <> Apropos of nothing, I would Really Like to see almost complex retired in favor of complex, and complex replaced where appropriate with holomorphic.

I agree with @AndrewD.Hwang. In algebra and in category theory, the term 'morphism' has been used to denote any 'natural' sort of mappings (e.g. a group homomorphism isn't necessarily invertible). However, in geometry and topology, it's the term 'map' that serves this purpose: we speak of continuous maps, of smooth maps, etc.; 'morphism' then denotes a 'bijective map' e.g. a homeomorphism, a diffeomorphism, etc. 'Symplectic map' or 'symplectic immersion' are used to speak of a smooth map $f$ pulling back the target symplectic form to the source symplectic form (note that these are immersions).
